# 'NSTextView' does not have a member named 'setString'

Tags: cocoa, swift

I am new to Cocoa,

I want to replace the content of a NSTextView.

I find a function named `setString` of NSText, and NSTextView inherits NSText.

So why do I get an error:

`NSTextView' does not have a member named 'setString`

Thank you.

Right now, I have to use NSTextView.insertText to insert some text.

Comment: Try NSTextView.setStringValue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual property is `string`. Objective-C generates getter and setter (if not read only) methods so you can override their behaviour. Swift has method observers for custom behaviour so you don't need custom getters/setters.

Assign to property directly:

```
let textView = NSTextView()
textView.string = "text"
```